# How can I check if someone is in a List

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

> Code:

```
@commands.command()
async def allow(self, ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    if member != None:
        if ctx.author.id in f'{allowedID}':
            with open('owner.json', 'a') as f:
                f.write(member.id)
    else:
        firstArg = (" ").join(content)
        user = bot.get_user(firstArg)
        if ctx.author.id in f'{allowedID}':
            if user != None:
                if user != user.Bot:
                    with open('owner.json', 'a') as f:
                        f.write(user.id)
```

> Error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
```

I want to check if someone is in the json but I always become this error and yet idk how I can fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't check integer in string, obviously it is not exists. change `ctx.author.id in f'{allowedID}'` to `str(ctx.author.id) in f'{allowedID}'` in your code.

```python
>> 2 in 'name'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-24283495773c> in <module>
----> 1 2 in 'name'
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int

>> str(2) in 'name'
False
```

Answer (score 0):

If `allowedID` is a list of integers,

```
if ctx.author.id in f'{allowedID}':
```

should be replaced with

```
if ctx.author.id in allowedID:
```

and if it's a list of strings, the line should be replaced with

```
if str(ctx.author.id) in allowedID:
```

What you're doing currently is checking whether an integer is in a string which is not something that python allows(You can only check whether a string is in a string).
Converting the id to a string will work in both the cases(`allowedID` is a list of integers/strings) but `if ctx.author.id in allowedID:` is better in the case that it's a list of integers since no conversion is required.